# how do I dynamically add options to a select tag based on array data?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is what I have

mypage.component.html

```
<select>
    <option>2 weeks</option>
    <option>1 Month </option>
    <option>6 Months</option>
</select>
```

mypage.component.ts

```
export class MyPageComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }
    public searchDates: Array<String> = [ "1 week", "2 weeks" ];

ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

How do I replace the hard coded options with content from the searchDates array? assuming the array will change in size from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngFor`:

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let a of searchDates">
        {{a}}
    </option>
</select>
```